# How to compare two models to be rendered with Markdown using Django?

Tags: python, django, version-control, markdown, difflib

What is the best way to check for changes (edited/added/deleted text) in a post between two post's versions (original and edited one)?

I am using *Markdown* so I am not sure if using *difflib.HtmlDiff* is a good idea. My goal is to mark with a green background the added text and with a red background the deleted ones, something similar like what [github](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4c5641dd92e5cfa0223f417f30d109ff998b8041) does.

Comment: Are you comparing the Markdown itself or the rendered Markdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out `ghdiff`, GitHub style HTML for unified diffs. It's [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghdiff), but there are [better docs on GitHub](https://github.com/kilink/ghdiff) currently. You'll need to `pip install ghdiff`.

Simple usage, assuming the markdown is in `markdown1` and `markdown2`.

```
import ghdiff
diff_as_html = ghdiff.diff(markdown1,markdown2)
```

Here's a more explicit demonstration though. Let's say you have these two markdown strings:

```
md1 = '''
# Hello world

I am text

* No really

'''

md2 = '''
# Hi world

I am text

* No really

'''
```

We can perform a diff on these

```
import ghdiff
diff_as_html = ghdiff.diff(md1,md2)
```

When rendered, it looks like this:

[image: ghdiff]

Here's the raw and the rendered in an IPython Notebook:

[image: raw and rendered in IPython notebook]

Comment: Thanks, applied to [my solution](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/fpuf/blob/master/fpuf/apps/material/business_rules/material.py#L151) sample here: http://uf.ctrl-alt-d.net/material/revisions/16/

Comment: Also, reading project code, it is not so far from my dirty solution ;)

Comment: @danihp - That's funny. Yeah, difflib (at least in Python 2.7) isn't very featureful. I've used [get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get%5Fclose%5Fmatches) for some interesting scraper logic, but nothing as fancy as what's needed for beautified diffs.

Answer (score 0):

**Try DiffMerge:**

http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

It works great!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use [this dirty code](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/fpuf/blob/master/fpuf/apps/material/business_rules/material.py#L127) wrote by myself in few minutes as first approach. I also compare markdown itself.

I'm also looking for a best way.

```
def canvis_html( before, after ):
    d = ''.join(
                  ndiff(
                    before.splitlines(1),
                    after.splitlines(1)
                        )
                     )

    estils = {'+':'color:green;', '-':'color:red;text-decoration:line-through;',}
    new = u""
    previous_zone = 'new'    
    for l in d.splitlines(1):
        l=l+u"  "
        zona = l[0]
        if zona in ( '+', '-'):
            if zona != previous_zone:
                #si havia obert una zona la tanco
                if previous_zone != 'new': new += u"</span>"
                #colorejo segons la zona  
                new += u"<span style='{estil};'>".format( estil = estils[zona])
                previous_zone = zona
            new += l[1:] 
        elif l.startswith( '?' ):
            pass
        else:
            new += l[1:]

    return new
```

[Here you can see edit results](http://uf.ctrl-alt-d.net/material/revisions/10/), as you can see, it is just a starting point if you should code yourself.